# Text Input from Bluetooth Barcode Scanner with no keyboard

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a react native app that receives input from a bluetooth barcode scanner which basically just acts as keyboard emulation. I'm receiving the input into a TextInput however I don't want to show the keyboard. However, if I dismiss the keyboard it doesn't accept input into the TextInput.

Is there any way to accept input from the barcode scanner without showing the keyboard?

Comment: Just Curious if you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @gsueagle2008 unfortunately I never found a good solution. I ended up having to open the iOS code that was generated in XCode and editing it in there.

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but,

There is a property called showSoftInputOnFocus in newer react-native versions. Setting this to false keeps the keyboard hidden.

Working for me on v0.60.0

[React-Native TextInput with focus but without keyboard showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639041/react-native-textinput-with-focus-but-without-keyboard-showing)