# React-Native TextInput with focus but without keyboard showing

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, qr-code

I'm developing an inventory system for my father's company and on of its requisites is to be able to use an external Barcode/QR Code scanner.

I've developed everything using the camera as well, but I really need to use the scanner **whithout** showing the keyboard.

Do any of you guys know if it's possible? if not, can it be done in any other way?

Comment: I have made a little search about this and seen that there is still not a solution for this on react native side. So I think you might need to right some native code to achieve that.

Comment: This may be what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199745/how-do-i-listen-to-keyboard-input-in-react-native

Comment: what is the purpose of using the TextInput here?

Comment: I don't find any requrement of using TextInput if not at all you need user interaction.

Comment: @Ravi The scanner works as an axternal keyboard, it writes the content and presses enter, thats why i nees a TextInput, so i can register the data

Comment: If scanner is writing I believe you will be getting data in string format, in that case you can directly have simple text/label.

Comment: @GustavoMartinsdoSantos Did you find any alternative solution to this? Facing the exactly same issue

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called `showSoftInputOnFocus` in newer react-native versions. Setting this to false keeps the keyboard hidden.

`<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} autoFocus={true}..../>`

Working for me on v0.60.0

Answer (score 0):

Wrap TouchableOpacity with ScrollView without any props which enables tapto open keyboard work. This Works both on ios and android now!

```
const [openKeyboard, setOpenKeyboard] = useState(autoFocus);

const onPressInput = useCallback(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
    setOpenKeyboard(true)
}, [inputRef]);

  <ScrollView
    >
        <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={1}
            style={[styles.container, style]}
            onPress={onPressInput}

        >
            {renderInputBox()}
            <View style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}>
                <TextInput
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    returnKeyType="done"
                    autoFocus={openKeyboard}
                    maxLength={codeLength}
                    ref={inputRef}
                />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
```